# Django queries: how to filter objects to exclude id which is in a list?

Tags: django, list

How can I filter in a query so the result excludes any object instances with ID belonging to a list?

Lets say I have:

```
object_id_list = [1, 5, 345]

MyObject.objects.filter(Q(time__gte=datetime.now()) & Q( ... what to put here? ... ))
```

Something in the style of `"SELECT * FROM ... WHERE id NOT IN (...)"`

Answer (score 263, accepted):

```
MyObject.objects.filter(time__gte=datetime.now()).exclude(id__in=object_id_list)
```

Comment: What is name of `MyObject.objects`? Where I can read about this class?

Comment: @Serge MyObject would just be relating to your Django model class whatever it may be. So for example you may have UserProfile.objects if you have a UserProfile model setup.

Comment: Thank you, but im asking right about `.objects`. What is it?

Comment: it's the default ModelManager.

Comment: you may use for single object as well. 
`MyObject.objects.filter(time__gte=datetime.now()).exclude(id=object_id)`

Answer (score 35):

You can also do this using the `Q` object:

```
from django.db.models import Q

MyObject.objects.filter(time__gte=datetime.now()).filter(~Q(id__in=object_id_list))
```

Comment: Does the `~` negate the filter?

Comment: yes, it does negate the filter

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.db import connection
def executeQuery(self, sql, params=[]):
  with connection.cursor() as cursor:
     cursor.execute(
        sql,
        params
      )
```

use:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
```

"""only add map(str, list) if your comparing integers"""

```
if len(list) > 0: # only if the list is not empty 
   executeQuery(f"SELECT * FROM WHERE id NOT IN ({({','.join(map(str, list))})})")
```